# Not able to connect the server while creating linked service for Postgresql(source), in data factory in azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created database and tables in postgres in linux virtual machine using shell scripts(vm created using azure).Now,I have to transfer those tables to Azure blob storage.For this,I created pipe line in data factory,but while creating linked service for the source (for which I mention IR as Auto resolve,server name as the name I used to ssh into the vm,port number as 5432,database name as the name of the database I created in postgres and username and password as the one which is used for the linux virtual machine).But when I did  Testconnection it gives error.
Can you tell where is the mistake?

Connection failed
ERROR [08001] [DataDirect][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Unexpected Network Error. ErrNum = 11003
 ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Can't connect to server.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

For transfer data from private network into azure blob storage, you need to use [Self-Hosted Integration Runtime.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#self-hosted-ir-network-environment)

> If you want to perform data integration securely in a private network
>   environment, which does not have a direct line-of-sight from the
>   public cloud environment, you can install a self-hosted IR on premises
>   environment behind your corporate firewall, or inside a virtual
>   private network. The self-hosted integration runtime only makes
>   outbound HTTP-based connections to open internet.

[image]